# Jquery Ajax response object document

Tags: jquery, ajax, svg

I have a web server that returns a svg. working perfectly.
I am trying to use JQUERY to not type in browser always the request.
But i dont know to load the response into a DIV.

```
  $.get("http://localhost/proiect/domr.php", { url:           "http://www.info.uaic.ro",type:"svg",hox:"html" },"xml" )
   .done(function(data) {
      alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
      $("#tree").html(data);
```

I sais data loaded object document.
And in my div with id=tree puts nothing. How can i put my data where my svg is stored in my div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("http://localhost/proiect/domr.php", { url:              "http://www.info.uaic.ro",type:"svg",hox:"html" },"xml" )
.done(function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  $("#tree").append(data);
```

.append() should be used instead of .html().

Comment: doesnt work, it says data loaded object docuement, and still no output . also in the console i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id='string' style='display:none;'>dd</textarea>
<script>
var string = $('#string').val();
var datastring = 'string' = string;
$.ajax{(
url:"http://www.info.uaic.ro";
type: "POST";
cache:false;
data:datastring;
success: function(html){
$("#tree").append(html);
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: What does `type:"svg"` do? (Hint: not what you think.) Also, `var datastring = 'string' = string` is an error: you can't assign a value to a literal. What does `append(html)` do? Append to _what_?

Comment: try the other answer i have posted

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me (note that #svg is a div):

```
$.ajax
  url: "myurl"
  type: "POST"
  complete: (data) =>
    $("#svg").append data.responseText
```